# how can i insert a dropDownListFor with Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have a dropDownListFor in my view, like this:

```
`@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.idResponsaveis, Model.responsaveis)
 <input type='button' value='Adicionar' onclick='adicionarResponsavel()' class='btn' />`
```

and i need add multiples dropDownList ever the user click in adicionarResponsavel().

My javascript code is:

```
function adicionarResponsavel(){

        var div = document.getElementById('listaResponsaveis');
        var node = document.createElement('div');
        node.setAttribute('id', 'div' + quantity);
        node.appendChild('@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.idResponsaveis, Model.responsaveis)');

        div.appendChild(node);

    }
```

The specific line with error is:

```
node.appendChild('@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.idResponsaveis, Model.responsaveis)');
```

Comment: Where is that javascript located?  A separate file, or in `script` tags on the page?  If it is in a separate file (well, any file that isn't .cshtml/.vbhtml), Razor syntax won't work at all.  All that said, even if this code is in a Razor file, I'm not 100% sure it would work.  First thing to try is putting that javascript in your Razor file, though.

Comment: javascript works fine with all rest, but only this line give error, i import the files in _Layout.

Comment: Like I said, if that javascript you have in the question is *not* in a Razor file (.cshtml/.vbhtml), it absolutely won't work.  Move that javascript into a Razor file, then try.  And you just now mentioned a line is giving you an error.  That's information you should include in your question.

Comment: Ahh now I understand, yes this is a javascript code snippet at the end of the page view in a block <script> </ script>. The view utilizes the razor syntax

Comment: Ah, okay.  Now what is the error you're getting in the console?

Comment: Only "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: I'm guessing you arent escaping the " properly, what does actually get output for the line the error is happening on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with jQuery

```
function adicionarResponsavel(){

    var div = document.getElementById('listaResponsaveis');
    var node = document.createElement('div');
    node.setAttribute('id', 'div' + quantity);

   var existingDropDownClone=$('#id-of-existing-select-box').clone();

   existingDropDownClone.appendTo($(node));
}
```